# PyroCMS admin panel not working in IE8

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, pyrocms

I try to hard on working admin panel in IE8 but admin panel not working. Specially add pages or select page.

Comment: I am not into PyroCMS but are there any error messages from the page? Is it working in other browsers?

Comment: what version are you using? Only since version 2.0.2 there is a good compatibility with IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Pyrocms admin panel is not compatible in IE8. Even the design of admin panel is  totally disturbed in IE8 and IE7.